# intersection homology poincare polynomial

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204224v1 paper author mention so-called *intersection homology poincare polynomial* (not being the usual poncare polynomial), but never defines it, though it is an unfamiliar term, even for google.

Anyone know how is this polynomial defined?

Answers appreciated!

Comment: "Poincare polynomial" for some graded group (such as intersection homology) probably means $p(t) = \sum_i (\text{rk } G_i) t^i$.

Comment: I see. I didn't know of intersection homology theory, that's the problem :) Thanks!